# Django extending user model with a onetoone, but have several model.py files in applications

Tags: python, django

I have a django project with many applications in it, each one has models.py for pieces that are related to that portion of the project (The specific application) though I am using django's model login and user auth but I need more data with that, I saw here:

```
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-permissions
```

That there is a way to create another model that has the extra information and make it a onetoone to the user.

The thing is, this extra data I need available to all my other applications, so what models.py do I stuff this new table to be built?

Comment: What is not clear? You have an extra model with a one-to-one to User. What else do you need?

Comment: I have several Apps? (I think its many apps to one django project right?) THat each have their own models.py, so where do I put this extra model in so that all the apps can see this extra data?  or I just did notice there is an accounts folder that was added I guess when I used Django user commands, so perhaps I put it in that empty models.py then I can check the extra data I am adding to an user (for authorization, not authentication) in all the apps I have in my project?

Comment: Have you looked at the [Django documentation on doing this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model)?

Comment: I don't understand why you think you need to do anything. The model is there; you can access it from any other code via the request.user or by importing the model and querying it directly.

Comment: So in the documentation Mihai Chelaru added, there was an example of a profile model the Employee, which has the one to one User.  THe question is, which models.py file do I put that class Employee into? Since I have many apps in my project ?Or does it matter?

Comment: Wherever you like. Preferably somewhere it makes logical sense, but Django doesn't care.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure since it was a onetoone if it mattered which models.py it went into.